# how to replace a script tag with iframe dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert a script tag after the iFrame tag. Here I want to find a script tag with data dash attribute and replace that element with iframe after that append a script tag.

Here is my code but not working.

```
(function ($) {
var target = $("script[id=token]");
var iframe = $('<iframe>', {
    src: "//" + getHostName(target.attr("src")) ,
    name: "MyFrame",
    class: 'Myforms ' + target.attr("data-unique"),
    frameborder: "0",
    scrolling: "no"        
}).insertAfter($('<span>'));

target.replaceWith(iframe);

function getHostName(url) {
    var l = document.createElement("a");
    l.href = url;
    return l.host;
}

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: see console there is an error...

Comment: There is no errors showing in console

Comment: Can you post your code for `getHostName()`?

Comment: updated my questions with `getHostName()`

Comment: Can you post your HTML ?

Comment: @sridharnetha Did you get it working?

Answer (score -1):

Please find below a working example, fetching BBC's homepage based on the URL of a non-existing script on bbc.com.

Your `insertAfter($('<span>'))` is not needed, but it shouldn't cause errors either.

```js
function getHostName(url) {
  var l = document.createElement("a");
  l.href = url;
  return l.host;
}

(function ($) {
  var target = $("script[id=token]");
  var iframe = $('<iframe>', {
    src: "//" + getHostName(target.attr("src")),
    name: "MyFrame",
    class: 'Myforms ' + target.attr("data-unique"),
    frameborder: "0",
    scrolling: "no"        
  });

  target.replaceWith(iframe);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="token" src="http://www.bbc.com/nonexistingscript.js" data-unique="gnjrls"></script>
```

For troubleshooting, check that your target allows framing, for example by testing that the iframe loads when added manually to the HTML. Also, note that the protocol-less iframe URL `"//" + getHostName(target.attr("src"))` does not work if you're testing locally without a web server, i.e. the URL shown in the address bar begins with `file:///`.